# How to know nearest X-axis tick value from my drag able rectangles in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/t4ka8atv/  . Now I got 2 drag able   `rectangles` one left and another right. I want to know nearest `x-axis` `tick` value from my drag able `rectangles` while sliding them through. How I can achieve this .

Comment: why did you delete your other question ? I had an answer for you

Comment: Sorry @thatOneGuy PM scrapped that plan , move on with other graph. I am sorry for that. Dont know you had any answer for that. Will post it again. Thanks for help

Comment: send me email address Ill email it to you

Comment: dutta.dibyendu2010atgmail.com , I will post that question again if any plan change. Again thanks a lot

Comment: @thatOneGuy posted a question, might be your the best to reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I added a `dragend` capability so it checks whats the closest tick on `dragend` :

```
.on('dragend', function(d) {
      console.log('dragendRight')
      var thisCoordinate = d3.mouse(this);
      checkXAxis(thisCoordinate);
    });
```

This passes current mouse coordinates to a function that checks which is closest. This is the function, fully commented so hopefully you will understand :

```
function checkXAxis(mousePoints) {

    var thisMouseX = mousePoints[0];
    var thisPointDist = 10000; //this is set to  1000 so the first tick checked will be the current 
    var thisPoint; //used to set the closest point
    var xAxis = document.getElementsByClassName('x axis'); //gets all x axis ticks
    var xAxisChildren = xAxis[0]; //gets the x axis children, i.e each tick

    for (var i = 0; i < xAxisChildren.childNodes.length; i++) { //loops through the ticks
      var thisTickX = xAxisChildren.childNodes[i].getBoundingClientRect().left - margin.left; //gets the tick position
      if(xAxisChildren.childNodes[i].localName != 'path'){ //this is to make sure you're only getting the ticks not paths
      if (Math.abs(thisMouseX - thisTickX) < thisPointDist) { //check if distance is smaller than last checked
        thisPointDist = Math.abs(thisMouseX - thisTickX) //sets distance
        thisPoint = xAxisChildren.childNodes[i].__data__; //gets the point which is closest at this time
      }
      }

    } 
    alert(thisPoint) //alert the closest point

  }
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/t4ka8atv/6/

Basically what this does is on drag end it goes through each child of the x axis, i.e each tick and gets the difference between the mouse coordinates and each tick and which ever one has the smallest difference it sets this as `thisPoint` variable. In the code I alert this, but you can do what ever you wish.

```js
var isXChecked = true,
  isYChecked = true;

var
  heightRect = 200,
  dragbarw = 20;

var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;





function drawRangeSelector(data, id) {
  window["widthRect1" + id] = 100;
  window["widthRect2" + id] = 100;

  var dragright = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on("drag", rdragresize)
    .on('dragend', function(d) {
      console.log('dragendRight')
      var thisCoordinate = d3.mouse(this);
      checkXAxis(thisCoordinate);
    });

  var dragleft = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on("drag", ldragresize)
    .on('dragend', function(d) {
      console.log('dragendLeft')
      var thisCoordinate = d3.mouse(this);
      checkXAxis(thisCoordinate);
    });

  function checkXAxis(mousePoints) {
  
    var thisMouseX = mousePoints[0];
    var thisPointDist = 10000; //this is set to  1000 so the first tick checked will be the current 
    var thisPoint; //used to set the closest point
    var xAxis = document.getElementsByClassName('x axis'); //gets all x axis ticks
    var xAxisChildren = xAxis[0]; //gets the x axis children, i.e each tick
    
    for (var i = 0; i < xAxisChildren.childNodes.length; i++) { //loops through the ticks
    console.log(xAxisChildren.childNodes[i])
    console.dir(xAxisChildren.childNodes[i])
      var thisTickX = xAxisChildren.childNodes[i].getBoundingClientRect().left - margin.left; //gets the tick position
      console.log(thisTickX)
      if(xAxisChildren.childNodes[i].localName != 'path'){ //this is to make sure you're only getting the ticks not paths
      if (Math.abs(thisMouseX - thisTickX) < thisPointDist) { //check if distance is smaller than last checked
        thisPointDist = Math.abs(thisMouseX - thisTickX) //sets distance
        thisPoint = xAxisChildren.childNodes[i].__data__; //gets the point which is closest at this time
      }
      }
      
    }
    console.log(thisPoint)
    
    console.dir(thisPoint)
    alert(thisPoint) //alert the closest point
     
  }

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }))
    .rangePoints([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

  var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) {
      return y(d.price);
    });


  var svg = d3.select("#" + id).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var div = d3.select("#" + id).append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

  svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  y.domain([0, d3.max(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.price;
  }))]);

  focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  focus.selectAll(".dot").data(data)
    .enter().append("circle").attr('class', 'dot')
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.price);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", .9);
      div.html(d.date + "<br/>" + d.price)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    });

  var newg = focus.append("g")
    .data([{
      x: width / 700,
      y: height / 4
    }]);


  window["dragrect" + id] = newg.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "active")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", window["widthRect1" + id])
    .attr("fill-opacity", .5)

  window["dragbarright" + id] = newg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x + window["widthRect1" + id] - (dragbarw / 2);
    })
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + (dragbarw/2); })
    .attr("id", "dragright" + id)
    .attr("height", height - dragbarw)
    .attr("width", dragbarw)
    .attr("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr("fill-opacity", .5)
    .attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
    .call(dragright);

  var newg1 = focus.append("g")
    .data([{
      x: width - 100,
      y: height / 4
    }]);

  window["dragrect1" + id] = newg1.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "active1")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", window["widthRect2" + id])
    .attr("fill-opacity", .5);
  window["dragbarleft" + id] = newg1.append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x - (dragbarw / 2);
    })
    //.attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + (dragbarw/2); })
    .attr("height", height - dragbarw)
    .attr("id", "dragleft" + id)
    .attr("width", dragbarw)
    .attr("fill", "lightblue")
    .attr("fill-opacity", .5)
    .attr("cursor", "ew-resize")
    .call(dragleft);

  function rdragresize(d) {

    if (isXChecked) {
      //Max x on the left is x - width 
      //Max x on the right is width of screen + (dragbarw/2)

      var limit2 = d3.select('#dragleft' + id).attr("x");

      var dragx = Math.max(d.x + (dragbarw / 2), Math.min(width, d.x + window["widthRect1" + id] + d3.event.dx));
      // console.log(parseFloat(limit2)-parseFloat(dragx))
      //console.log(parseInt(limit2))
      if ((parseFloat(limit2) - parseFloat(dragx)) >= 30.00) {
        //recalculate width
        window["widthRect1" + id] = dragx - d.x;

        //move the right drag handle
        window["dragbarright" + id]
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return dragx - (dragbarw / 2)
          });

        //resize the drag rectangle
        //as we are only resizing from the right, the x coordinate does not need to change
        window["dragrect" + id]
          .attr("width", window["widthRect1" + id]);
      }

    }
  }

  function ldragresize(d) {

    if (isXChecked) {
      var oldx = d.x;

      //Max x on the right is x + width - dragbarw
      //Max x on the left is 0 - (dragbarw/2)
      var limit1 = d3.select('#dragright' + id).attr("x");


      d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(d.x + window["widthRect2" + id] - (dragbarw / 2), d3.event.x));
      //console.log(parseFloat(d.x)-parseFloat(limit1))
      if ((parseFloat(d.x) - parseFloat(limit1)) >= 50.00) {
        window["widthRect2" + id] = window["widthRect2" + id] + (oldx - d.x);
        window["dragbarleft" + id]
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x - (dragbarw / 2);
          });

        window["dragrect1" + id]
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x;
          })
          .attr("width", window["widthRect2" + id]);
      } else {
        d.x = oldx;
      }

    }
  }



}


function type(d) {
  d.date = d.date;
  d.price = +d.price;
  return d;
}

var data = [{
  "date": "A",
  "price": 0
}, {
  "date": "B",
  "price": 1
}, {
  "date": "C",
  "price": 2
}, {
  "date": "D",
  "price": 0
}, {
  "date": "E",
  "price": 2
}, {
  "date": "F",
  "price": 0
}, {
  "date": "G",
  "price": 4
}, {
  "date": "H",
  "price": 3
}, {
  "date": "I",
  "price": 0
}, {
  "date": "J",
  "price": 0
}, {
  "date": "K",
  "price": 3
}];

drawRangeSelector(data, 'charts');
drawRangeSelector(data, 'charts1');
```

```css
svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id='charts'>
    <div id='charts1'>
    </div>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks perfect @thisOneGuy .I will accept your answer . Thanks

Comment: So if I have to get the nearest x-Axis while `dragging` not `drag end` , I should execute this  login on `drag` event right ?

Comment: exactly :) but if you do this remove the alert otherwise it will fire every movement

Comment: `thisPointDist` is need to be adjusted for me , because in my application the graphs are appearing much smaller. I saw that first x-axis tick label that's `A` stays the same even if you have crossed `D`, after that it changes in expected duration but in pace of `E` it shows `B`  for `F` it shows `C` like that

Comment: probably due to the offset of your graph. look at the variable thisTickX in the for loop. This gets the position of the actual tick. If you play with that value you should be okay.

Comment: Sure @thisOneGuy will play with it and let you know. But your concept is perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110263/discussion-between-dibyendu-dutta-and-thisoneguy).